# Theme Development: Adding custom handle bar helpers

Tags: ghost-blog

For the [techno theme](https://github.com/mronemous/ghost-theme-techno) I wanted to make custom hb helpers and configuration available to users.  To do this I applied an override to the [ghost root]/index.js.

The code below searches for index.js in the current theme folder and runs it.

```
var ghost = require('./core'),
    errors = require('./core/server/errorHandling');

ghost()
.then(function (param) {

    var settings = require('./core/server/api').settings;

    settings
        .read({key: 'activeTheme', context: {internal: true}})
        .then(function (result) {

            try {
                require('./content/themes/' + result.value + '/index')();
            }
            catch (e) {
                //No custom index found, or it wasn't a proper module.
            }

        });
})
.otherwise(function (err) {
    errors.logErrorAndExit(err, err.context, err.help);
});
```

The theme level index.js injects custom blog variables (from a config file) and hb helpers.

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    downsize = require('downsize'),
    blogVariable = require('../../../core/server/config/theme');

module.exports = function() {

    //This block allows configuration to be available in the hb templates.
    var blogConfig = blogVariable();
    var config = require('./config') || {};
    blogConfig.theme = config;
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(blogConfig));

    ////Custom hb helpers////

    hbs.registerHelper('excerpt', function (options) {

        ...

        return new hbs.handlebars.SafeString(excerpt);
    });

    ...

};
```

An example of using the custom blog variables is below.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="{{@blog.theme.author.github}}" class="btn-social btn-outline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a>
    </li>
...
```

Is there a better way to do this in Ghost 0.4.2?  I do not like having users override the ghost core index.js file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a blog post explaining how to do this only by modifying the `config.js` file, and adding a file to the root directory. I agree with the author that this is more likely to be update-proof. http://zackehh.com/safely-creating-custom-handlebars-helpers/

Add:

```
require('./helpers')();
```

To the top of `config.js`

And add helpers to your `helpers.js` file like so:

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');

module.exports = function(){  
    hbs.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
      return JSON.stringify(context);
    });
};
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because its the best solution if I kept the config on the server side.  I ended up moving the config to the client side and used knockoutjs for injecting the config on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, there was a post about this a little while ago on the forums, however you can add your own helpers.js file to the core folder for example...

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs')

// quick function for an example
registerHelper = function(){

    hbs.registerHelper('ifNthItem', function(nthItem, currentCount, offset, options) {
        if((currentCount+ offset)%(nthItem) == 0) {
            return options.fn(this);
        } else {
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = registerHelper;
```

Then just link this into the index.js

```
var when      = require('when'),
    bootstrap = require('./bootstrap'),
    scopa = require('./helpers');

    scopa();
```

At least this way your not modifying the core index.js but the helpers.js instead.